# Finding date of SVN revision directory has been updated to

Tags: svn

The "svn info" command shows me the revision that a local directory has been updated to. For example:

```
rpsim1:~/linux_lib/tao/python/pytao/gui/doc> svn info $ACC_ROOT_DIR/forest
Path: /nfs/acc/libs/Linux_x86_64_intel/devel/forest
Working Copy Root Path: /nfs/acc/libs/Linux_x86_64_intel/devel/forest
URL: https://accserv.lepp.cornell.edu/svn/packages/forest
Repository Root: https://accserv.lepp.cornell.edu/svn
Repository UUID: a2b8903e-c52d-0410-b615-d38a5222fef6
Revision: 46868
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: dcs16
Last Changed Rev: 46050
Last Changed Date: 2019-09-12 11:09:19 -0400 (Thu, 12 Sep 2019)
```

Notice that the directory has been updated to 46868 which is different from the last changed revision which is 46050.

Now in the case where I cannot query the Repository itself, is there an SVN command I can use to find the date associated with the revision the local directory has been updated to? I tried but the "svn log" command does not show this.

Comment: `svn log -q -v https://accserv.lepp.cornell.edu/svn/packages/forest -l 10` would need that repository to query, so you'd might need an offline repository instead of the working copy. see [svnbook.red-bean.com](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Comment: @Martin Zeitler  Unfortunately `svn log` only gives info for revisions where code has been modified in the directory under consideration. This is true for directories in the Repository as well. Additionally, an offline repository is not feasible in my case.

Comment: Think that in clients alike SmartSVN, this is accomplished by caching... but on the CLI, there is no cache. Locally one usually can query only what's in the `.svn` directory - but the query might require `svnserve` (therefore a local repository would make sense, since there is no other cache one could query).

Comment: @Martin Zeitler I'm not understanding you. When I use the `svn log` command you give above I do not get info on revision 46868. Just revision 46050 and earlier revisions. So this would not be a solution even for the case where I can query the Repository.